# Loading ADF causes crash in Explorer

Tags: google-project-tango

When I create an ADF with the AreaLearning Demo in Java then open the ADF in Project Tango Explorer it crashes every time. I first wrote my own Java ADF creator app, and it crashed Explorer so I decided to try the Java Area Learning demo to see what I did wrong, but it crashed Explorer too.
Is there an incompatibility? Shouldn't an ADF be an ADF? I just want to make sure I'm not missing something, or messing something up.Thanks.

Comment: Is the TangoCore and BSP updated?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not disconnecting Tango in onPause() method of your Activity. You can disconnect the Tango by adding the following lines in your Activity, where *mIsConnected* is a boolean set to be true at once the Tango gets connected.

```
 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
     super.onPause();
     if (mIsConnected) {
         mTango.disconnect();
         tangoCameraPreview.disconnectFromTangoCamera();
         mIsConnected = false;
     }
  }
```

Comment: It's disconnecting, I have that same exact code in my onPause() method.. I also totally close my app, reboot my machine, , then open Tango Explorer, load ADF and Tango Explorer crashes. Same thing happens when I use the Area Description Java example to record my ADF and then use Explorer to see ADF.....crash.

Answer (score 0):

It was not disconnecting, but it wasn't in onPause, it was in onDestroy. The Google example doesn't mTango.disconnect() in Destroy, but it does in onPause.....I put the disconnect in onDestroy too and I could open my ADF in Explorer.......so @ABI you were right, but I had only checked the onPause method you listed. Thanks